# QGIS returns "invalid layer" when adding a WMS layer

Tags: qgis, wms

I want to add a WMS layer in my map. I select the server and obtain the list of layers that are published there. I select one of them (the problem is the same with all layers), but QGIS does not load it, instead returning a message saying **invalid layer - Impossible to calculate extension**.

I think it could be a problem of projection, because it is not declared by the server, and I know it is lat/lon WGS84 (not projected).

Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is "Impossible to calculate extension"? A quick google doesn't find much of anything for that term.

Comment: I guess it should be "extent".

Comment: yes it could be extent ... I have QGIS in italian so the message is in italian "impossibile calcolare l'estensione"

Comment: ok. I have searched google with the english message, and found something. but the solution they suggest is on server side, that I cant control now. So I am interested in some client-side solution ...

Comment: You shouldn't request a map in a CRS that the WMS doesn't advertise as being supported (according to the WMS specification).  Which I guess is the root cause of the reported error.  But now QGIS will do the reprojection for you, a different behaviour from older QGIS versions.